# I want to attach a click event to an isolated SceneBuilder object

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm working on adding objects to the viewer using the SceneBuilder extension. Also, if I place it so that it overlaps with a ghosting object in the background, I am having trouble because the ghosting object becomes invisible.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

After applying the isolate processing, the ghosting object in the background becomes visible, but it is no longer clickable.

I need to meet both requirements.

Thank you for your cooperation.

Comment: As with your other Stack Overflow post, could you please clarify what you're trying to do, potentially including some screenshots as well? In the title you're asking for one thing, but then you mention a "ghosting object becoming invisible"?